# Kubernetes Deployment Spec Object

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

What are the required YAML properties in Kubernetes for a DeploymentSpec Object?

Is it metadata, apiVersion, kind, spec, selector, and template?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Kubernetes official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#required-fields), every kubernetes object needs:

1. apiVersion - Which version of the Kubernetes API you're using to create this object
2. kind - What kind of object you want to create
3. metadata - Data that helps uniquely identify the object, including a name string, UID, and optional namespace
4. spec - What state you desire for the object

and format of "spec" is different for every Kubernetes object, so the required values would be different too.

And according to [DeploymentSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/#DeploymentSpec), required values for Deployment Spec are:

1. selector
2. template

but if you use specific conditions like "conditions", you will need to fill some required fields for them (like conditions.status)